# move sub directories up one level to root in linux

Tags: linux, apache-2.2

I have a directory structure like this:-

```
/root/directory/subdirectory1
/root/directory/subdirectory2
/root/directory/subdirectory3
/root/directory/subdirectory4
```

I need all subdirectories to move up 1 level so they are off the root, can someone please help me with the correct syntax from a shell prompt please.

Thanks

Jonathan

Answer (score 2):

```
cd /root/directory/
mv ./subdirectory* ../
```

Comment: Thanks, is there a way to do it without having to specify the names of the subdirectories as there are about 50.

Thanks

Jonathan

Answer (score 2):

```
mv /root/directory/* /root/
```

Answer (score 0):

Two good references you should bookmark:

http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/index.html

http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/index.html

These will help you immeasurably in your bash-fu adventures.